# Is there a limit on the number of owners or board members assigned to a board, and/or the number of members assigned to a card on Trello?

Tags: trello

Just wondering if any limits have been placed (or may in the future be placed) on these participation levels, as our office employs approximately 80 individuals, nearly 60 of which would require active participation in at least one board.

Answer (score 3):

There is **no limit** on:

- the number of members on a board
- the number of members in an org
- the number of board or organization owners
- the number of members assigned to a card

Comment: Or, rather, the limits are practical... not technical. :)